# Numba type error cannot store {i8*, i32, i8*, i8*, i32}* to i8*: mismatching types

Tags: python, numba

I'm having issues converting simple python code to Numba, already spent hours on ChatGPT3 and the issue persisted, saying

> Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering) cannot store
> {i8*, i32, i8*, i8*, i32}* to i8*: mismatching types

I don't have the slighest clue for why it can't store something, all datatypes seem to match the required formats. Before calling the `create_full_tree` method, I'm initializing `new_genotype = new_genotype_type.copy()` and parsing the .bnf file into `grammar`. The other parameters are properly typed and `find_references` numba function works fine outsite the function.

```
grammar = Dict.empty(key_type=types.unicode_type, value_type=types.ListType(types.ListType(types.unicode_type)))
production_type = types.ListType(types.int64)
new_genotype_type = Dict.empty(
    key_type=types.unicode_type,
    value_type=production_type
)

@jit(nopython=True)
def create_full_tree(grammar, genotype,first_symbol, ref_by_dict, count_refs_dict, non_terminals_set):
    # for every non-terminal, we create a vector of size equal to the upper bound of productions
    non_terminals_list = list(non_terminals_set)
    for symbol_index in prange(len(non_terminals_list)):
        print(symbol_index)
        symbol = non_terminals_list[symbol_index]

        upper_bound = find_references(symbol, first_symbol, ref_by_dict, count_refs_dict)

        productions_length = len(grammar[symbol])
        possible_productions = List.empty_list(types.int64)
        for i in range(upper_bound):
            #codon = random_int(0, productions_length - 1)
            possible_productions.append(0)

        genotype[symbol] = possible_productions
```

`non_terminals_set` is a `reflected set(unicode_type)` and my numba version is `0.57`

Already tried initializing `possible_productions` using `np.zeros`, appending every item manually, etcs, to no avail: numba always fails at the assignment to `genotype`

This is how I'm calling the function

```
def create_genotype(grammar_file='variable_depth.bnf', max_depth=6, option='full'):
    new_genotype = new_genotype_type.copy()

    desired_depth_grammar, non_terminals, terminals = create_grammar_from_bnf(grammar_file, max_depth)
    first_symbol = next(iter(desired_depth_grammar.keys()))

    count_refs, ref_by = calculate_non_terminal_references(desired_depth_grammar, non_terminals)

    if option == 'full':
        create_full_tree(desired_depth_grammar, new_genotype, first_symbol, ref_by, count_refs, non_terminals)
    elif option == 'probabilistic':
        create_individual_probabilistic(desired_depth_grammar, max_depth, new_genotype, first_symbol, 0)
    return new_genotype, desired_depth_grammar


create_genotype(max_depth=10)
```

The function `calculate_non_terminal_references` works as expected with numba types and logic

Comment: What does `non_terminals_set` look like? And what (exactly) is its type?

Comment: Which version of Numba are you using?

Comment: @9769953 complemented the question with them. `non_terminals_set` is `{'<expr>', '<expr7>', '<expr5>', '<expr6>', '<expr8>', '<uop>', '<expr4>', '<op>', '<integer>', '<non-zero-digit>', '<start>', '<number>', '<digit>', '<expr1>', '<expr9>', '<expr2>', '<expr3>'}`

Comment: How are you calling the function?

Comment: @Raphael updated the question with the call context

Comment: Try explicitly specifying signatures, as in `@jit(int32(int32, int32))` shown
 https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html